# Why this only works for the first div?

Tags: javascript, php, hide, show, do-while

I have this js function to show/hide a div id="xdata"

```
function xdataview(){
var estado = document.getElementById('xdata').style.visibility;

if (estado==="hidden"){
document.getElementById('xdata').style.visibility = "visible";
} else {
document.getElementById('xdata').style.visibility = "hidden";
}
}
```

and this inside a do while PHP loop

```
<div id="xdata" class="extradata">
<?php
   $saidas = $row_RSplano['TotalSaidas'];
   $entradas = $row_RSplano['TotalEntradas'];
   $saldo = $saidas - $entradas;
   echo "S:" . $saidas . " / " . "E:" . $entradas . "  >>>> SALDO:" . $saldo; 
?>
</div>
```

the problem is that this only work for the first div in my sql result. I not can't hide/show the second row div

Comment: IDs must be unique. You can't reuse them. You should select by the class name, and iterate the result in a loop.

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique on each page

Comment: ID's are unique, that's why it only works on the first element, there shouldn't be any more elements with that ID.

Comment: you can use `document.querySelectorAll('.extradata')` to select the `<div>`'s by classname

Comment: I try to use var estado = document.getElementsByClassName('extradata').style.visibility;
didn't work

Comment: @CarlosMartins: As I said in my first comment, you need to iterate the result in a loop. Don't you know how to do that?

Comment: Start by reading some beginner's tutorials. [Learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it

```
divs=document.getElementsByTagName("DIV"); 
 for (theDiv in divs) { 
 if (divs[theDiv].className=="extradata") divs[theDiv].style.visibility="hidden"; 
 }
```

thanks to you all